# Можно ли отслеживать уходящие на сервер запросы из js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend, fetch

Есть странная задача, нужно отслеживать все `xmlhttprequest/fetch` запросы уходящие со страницы из стороннего js кода.
Т.е. каждый раз когда откуда-нибудь из кода фронта отправляется запрос на сервер, на это должен реагировать другой js код.

Просто вызывать функции перед отправкой запросов нет возможности, так как два фрагмента кода не могут между собой взаимодействовать, просто код который должен реагировать подключается со стороны.

Вот такая вот задача, заранее спасибо за любой ответ или комментарий.

Comment: Да, можно. Monkey patching.

Comment: в сторону service workers посмотри

Comment: @Vladislav, но service worker вроде сможет только в рамках домена перехватывать?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Vladislav - спасибо, оба метода прекрасно подходят под мою задачу. Чуть позже напишу ответ с кодом